# How to make a WHERE something OR something_else query in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have quickly browsed through the following [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/) to see how I can make a `WHERE ... OR` query in Django. But I couldn't find it, maybe I'm too tired. So I'm asking it here instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) e.g. from the docs

```
Q(question__startswith='Who') | Q(question__startswith='What')
```

is the same as

```
WHERE question LIKE 'Who%' OR question LIKE 'What%'
```